# How to merge 500 million table with another 500 million table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to merge two 500M+ row tables.

What is the best method to merge them?

I just need to display the records from these two SQL-Server tables if somebody searches on my webpage.

These are fixed tables, no one will ever change data in these tables once they are live.

```
create a view myview as select * from table1 union select * from table2
```

Is there any harm using the above method?

If I start merging 500M rows it will run for days and if machine reboots it will make the database go into recovery mode, and then I have to start from the beginning again.

**Why Am I merging these table?**

- I have a website which provides a search on the person table.
- This table have columns like Name, Address, Age etc
- We got 500 million similar .txt files which we loaded into some other
  table.
- Now we want the website search page to query both tables to see if
  a person exists in the table.
- We get similar .txt files of 100 million or 20 million, which we load
  to this huge table.

**How we are currently doing it?**

- We import the .txt files into separate tables ( some columns are different
  in .txt)
- Then we arrange the columns and do the data type conversions
- Then insert this staging table into the liveCopy huge table ( in
  test environment)

We have SQL server 2008 R2

- Can we use table partitioning for performance benefits?
- Is it ok to create monthly small tables and create a view on top of
  them?
- How can indexing be done in this case?

We only load new data once in a month and do the select

Does **replication** help?

**Biggest issue I am facing is managing huge tables.**

I hope I explained the situation .

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Why would you want to do a UNION of two 500M+ row tables? Is anyone actually gonna read a page with 1G+ rows.

Comment: I think to give a proper answer that fits your needs the best, you will have to give more details about the data, how it is going to be manipulated on the page, and why they need to see it all at once.

Comment: Too little information here to say anything useful. There is no intrinsic "harm" in this method. How are you querying this view? What indexes are defined? You probably meant UNION ALL.

Comment: 500 Million Records, No one will ever change the data. cool 

just go ahead and add all the indexes you can.

Comment: is there any reason there are two tables? is the data split by type or date, etc that you can leverage into a faster search?  You really need to provide more info if you want a good answer.

Comment: Dear Experts, I have edited the question . I hope it is more clear now. Thanks & Regards

Comment: Sorry, but - 500 million rows is not small, but it is not really BIG. It is a nice medium size table that SQL Server has no problem merging with in a couple of minutes on a medium hardware server (I.e. not a laptop or a small VM).

Comment: thanks Frazz. website is just interest in one person search.   So where clause on firstname

Comment: thanks Elias. I have updated the question to clarify my problem situation.

Comment: thanks usr.  I have updated the question to clarify my problem situation. I am looking for the solution in which both tables acts as a single table without merging them. This will save me from merging  data every month.

Comment: thanks tomtom have 64gb RAM

Comment: thanks KM.   both tables are similar.  tables have person information like name , address, phone .    no key. no constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is truly just to move the data from the two tables into one table, you will want to do it in batches - 100K records at a time, or something like that.  I'd guess you crashed before because your T-Log got full, although that's just speculation.  Make sure to throw in a checkpoint after each batch if you are in Full recovery mode.

That said, I agree with all the comments that you should provide why you are doing this - it may not be necessary at all.

Comment: thanks Dave. I have tried to explain the question more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

1) Usually developers, to achieve more performance, are splitting large tables into smaller ones and call this as partitioning (horizontal to be more precise, because there is also vertical one). Your view is a sample of such partitions joined. Of course, it is mostly used to split a large amount of data into range of values (for example, table1 contains records with column [col1] < 0, while table2 with [col1] >= 0). But even for unsorted data it is ok too, because you get more room for speed improvements. For example - parallel reads if put tables to different storages. So this is a good choice.

2) Another way is to use MERGE statement supported in SQL Server 2008 and higher - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

3) Of course you can copy using INSERT+DELETE, but in this case or in case of MERGE command used do this in a small batches. Smth like:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10000
DECLARE @Count [int] = 1
WHILE @Count > 0 BEGIN
    ... INSERT+DELETE/MERGE transcation...

    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: Thanks stan. I will commit after  every 0.1 million records inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at an Indexed View.
In this way, you can set up indexes on your view and get the best performance out of it.  The expensive part of using Indexed Views is in the CRUD operations - but for read performance it would be your best solution.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/

Comment: Thanks blorkfish. when I asked to improve my sql page response
I have a single table with 10 columns.
Table is  person(name,adrress,phone,email.......15 more columns)
all searched columns are indexed..
no key on table..
no constraints on table ..
I get advice from a BUSINESS DATA WAREHOUSE guru:
1: I can't tell you for sure.
2: I think your issue is to optimize your db's   and setup a write Master and multiple read slaves
3: More hardware always helps
but something tells me hardware isn't your main problem..

Answer (score 2):

If the two tables are linked one to one, then you are wasting the cpu time a lot for each read. Especially that you mentioned that the tables don't change at all. You should have only one table in this case.
Try creating a new table including (at least) the two columns from the two tables.
You can do this by:

> Select into newTable
>
> ```
>     from A left join B on A.x=B.y
> ```

or (if some people don't have the information of the text file)

> Select into newTable
>
> ```
>     from A inner join B on A.x=B.y
> ```

And note that you have to have made index on the join fields at least (to speed up the process).

More details about the fields may help giving more precise answer as well.

Comment: Thanks Alisa for advice.  is there any performance benefit of joining tables.  If I ignore the data insertion effort/cost,  Isnt the merged table is better than joined small tables. But it seems to be contrary to partition tables.  Please execuse me for my less knowledge.

Comment: The join is preferred only when we have two tables and we don't want to merge them. In other words, merging may cause redundancy. But here, as I mentioned, if the relation between two tables is one-to-one, then there is no redundancy in merging into one table.

Answer (score -1):

its too late but hope it will help someone.

I have multiple mysql database on different servers of the same data.
every database have more then 400 Million rows. it was basically of caller ID mobile application. so we want to create a centerilize database of a server. so firstly I have allowed remote connection to every database. and then write a function in which I take 1 million rows form database1 and save that to css file. and the use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. all the operation have take 5 days.and now I have a centriole database of about 1.8 billion rows. also I have apply indexes on multiple columns so it is easily to search. the response time is about 500 to 700 milli seconds.

here is the nodeJs code of what I have done

```
async function saveDataFromFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const results = await sequelize.query(
                `LOAD DATA INFILE '${filePath}' IGNORE  INTO TABLE contactsdb FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (countryId,nationalNumber,personName)`
            );
            resolve({ status: true, results: results[0] });
        } catch (err) {
            reject({
                status: false,
                message: err,
            });
        }
    });
}
```